# SharePoint 2010 - ASP.net List folders from network location

Tags: asp.net, html

New to SharePoint & ASP is there any way to simply list folders from a given network path and display them in a SharePoint webpage?

Thanks
Niall

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using the Page viewer webpart. Simply drop it on the page and point it to a network folder.

Comment: That;s great and works. But is there anyway I can pull that into a table as I want to list owners of folders in line with them being pulled in. Does that make sense?

Comment: Well, you could create a visual webpart that gets the file information into a collection and binds it to a grid view. Is that more like what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes thats more along the lines of what I require.